# Getting error 500 in my Azure apim while trying to connect to RavenDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ravendb, azure-keyvault, azure-api-management

Locally, my api is working fine but in the Azure apim when i add these lines in the controller (to access my RavenDB) i get an internal server error 500.

[image: Injecting IAsyncDocumentSession code]

[image: Http Response]

Here is the startup configuration:

[image: startup configuration]

i'm also using AzureKeyVault to get the certificate to access my RavenDB.

[image: DocumentStoreFactory using AzureKeyVault]

I added the apim's IP in the allowed IPs of RavenDB Cloud, without success.

**The question is, how can i fix that ?**

Feel free to ask in case you need more informations.

**EDIT**
I recently had more information about the error 500
[image: Error 500 with SSL]

**Problem solved**
Waiting for @TinyWang to write his anwser instead of a comment.
You can find the things that worked for me in the comments.

Comment: Apim works like a gate before your api, hence apim's IP is no need to add to db's allowed list but the IP of the server that you deployed your project.

Comment: @TinyWang Thx for your answer, my project is a simple API (there is no frontend), i published it on Azure (App Service + apim) & the RavenDB is on RavenDB Cloud.

Comment: Hi @Adrioca, thanks for your reply and could you pls call your api directly without using apim url? I mean if your api is `domain/api/users`(you said it's ok locally), and after deploying to azure, the url will turn to sitename.azurewebsites.net/api/users, could you pls hit this link to test if the 500 comes from your program but not apim?(I'm afraid it really comes from your program). And if it really the backend code issue, we need to chase the logger to see where's the exception. And maybe that's really failed to connect  the database, then let's check if the web app is is allowed by db

Comment: See [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips) for obtain azure web app ip.

Comment: Hi @TinyWang, i may have found the source of the problem, i edited the question.

Comment: I saw this `The system can not find the file specified` in the screenshot and here, I'm afraid the folder `c:/user/xxxxx` is the folder in your local computer, but pls note after you publish your app to azure, the environment has changed and you may use kudu to see the server environment (`https://your-site-name.scm.azurewebsites.net`  in nav bar -> debug console-> cmd  see the folder structure). And then you can adjust the folder in your code.

Comment: Perfect, you just solved the problem ! It works :D

Comment: @TinyWang it seems i cannot accept your comment as an answer. Do you want to write an answer so i can validate it and you can take the credit for helping me?

Here is how i solved the problem thanks to your comment(s) :
- I don't use AzureKeyVault anymore, i store the certificate directly in the API's folder
- I uploaded the certificate in the App Service of Azure using kudu in the C:\home\site\wwwroot> 
- Finally, i changed the x509KeyStorageFlags from DefaultKeySet to MachineKeySet

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort on this case and I'm glad to see it's solved now. I'v sum up below. Happy coding : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up here and end this case:

According to the error message, we can see it comes from the error route in the server but not something wrong with azure apim. We can use kudu for azure web app to check the folder structure of server.

And as op said in the comment above, he chose to uploaded the certificate to the server.

> I uploaded the certificate in the App Service of Azure using kudu in
> the C:\home\site\wwwroot> - Finally, i changed the x509KeyStorageFlags
> from DefaultKeySet to MachineKeySet